# ModelForm with Instance = Session ID

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a custom form for my users, so they can edit their profile.

So, when they login, I save the user ID in the session, and try to display the custom form (made of 3 classes) with the user data inside, but it does not work...

forms.py:

```
class EditUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

class EditUserProfilePublic(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfilePublic
        fields = ['website', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'google', 'books_frequency', 'favorite_types_of_books', 'hobbies', 'quote']

class EditUserProfilePrivate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfilePrivate
        fields = ['address', 'address_bis', 'zipcode', 'city']
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        member = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['user_id'])
        formUser = EditUser(instance=member)
        formPublic = EditUserProfilePublic(instance=member)
        formPrivate = EditUserProfilePrivate(instance=member)

    return render(request, 'membres/edit_user.html', locals())
```

template.html

```
<div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">
    <div class="row collapse prefix-radius">
        <label for="{{ formPublic.website.id_for_label }}">Site internet</label>
        <div class="large-2 medium-2 small-2 columns">
            <span class="prefix"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 medium-10 small-10 columns">
            {{ formPublic.website }}
        </div>
   </div>
</div> (and so on)
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="avatars/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class UserProfilePublic(models.Model):
    FREQUENCY_CHOICES = (
        ('', ''),
        ('1', 'Moins de 2 romans'),
        ('2', 'Entre 2 et 5 romans'),
        ('3', 'Entre 6 et 10 romans'),
        ('4', 'Plus de 2 romans')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
    google = models.URLField(blank=True)
    hobbies = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    books_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FREQUENCY_CHOICES, default='')
    favorite_types_of_books = models.TextField(blank=True)
    favorite_books = models.TextField(blank=True)
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class UserProfilePrivate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    address_bis = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

My form remains empty without any error displayed...
By the way, could I use the admin tool to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to store the user ID in the session, or to query the User table in your view. The user ID is already in the session, because that's simply how login works, and since they are logged in `request.user` is already the relevant User instance.

However, you *do* need to pass the actual UserProfilePublic and UserProfilePrivate instances to the relevant forms, rather than the User instance. So:

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request):
    formUser = EditUser(instance=request.user)
    formPublic = EditUserProfilePublic(instance=request.user.userprofilepublic)
    formPrivate = EditUserProfilePrivate(instance=request.user.userprofileprivate)
```

This assumes that your User class has a one-to-one relationship with both UserProfilePublic and UserProfilePrivate, and you haven't changed the related_name attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Where can I find all variables stored during the login? I tried your solution and it works for the formUser but not for the other. I have a one-to-one relationship between User and each Profile class, but nothing in the User class. Actually, I haven't overriden/extended the User class, I created new classes with the one-to-one (thought it was the best practices)

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "variables stored during the login" - you don't need that, you just need `request.user` as I showed. What exactly happens for the other forms? Do you get an error? You may need to show the definitions for the profile classes.

Comment: I edited my first post to add the classes. The error I get is "User has no userprofileprivate."

Comment: No news from there? Daniel, can you help me please?

Comment: Hello Daniel, there's nothing to be done to solve my problem? I am ok to redo my classes if needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, any help? I am still stuck :(.

Comment: Actually, I tried again and now it's working. I have no idea why it was not previously, and still don't get where user.userprofilepublic comes from since userprofilepublic is never set, but anyway, the most important is: it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The instance to your EditUserProfilePublic form should be instance of the UserProfilePublic model, you are passing User instance. Something like

formPublic = EditUserProfilePublic(instance=member.userprofilepublic)

And the same for EditUserProfilePrivate form.

-